# Codename One EasyThread.addGlobalErrorListener usage

Tags: codenameone

I didn't understand exactly how to use [`addGlobalErrorListener(EasyThread.ErrorListener err)`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/util/EasyThread.html#addGlobalErrorListener-com.codename1.util.EasyThread.ErrorListener-).

Let's go to my code in the `init()`:

```
        // Pro only feature (disabled)
        Log.bindCrashProtection(false);

        // Custom EDT error handling
        CN.addEdtErrorHandler(e -> {
            Log.p("\n\n--- EDT CRASH REPORT ---\n", Log.ERROR);
            Log.e((Throwable) e.getSource());
            Server.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("EDT Exception", "Please be patient, report the following ERROR to the developers and then kill the app:\n\n" + e.getSource().toString(), null, null);
        });

        // Custom EasyThread error handling
        EasyThread.addGlobalErrorListener((t, c, e) -> {
            CN.callSerially(() -> {
                Log.p("\n\n--- Easy Thread CRASH REPORT ---\n", Log.ERROR);
                Log.p("Thead name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Log.e(e);
                Server.sendLogAsync();
                Dialog.show("EDT Exception", "Please be patient, report the following ERROR to the developers and then kill the app:\n\n" + e.getMessage(), null, null);
            });
        });
```

Code to test EDT:

```
CN.callSerially(() -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Example of IllegalStateException in EDT");
        })
```

Code to test EasyThread:

```
thread.run(() -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Example of IllegalStateException in EasyThread");
        });
```

As you can guess, `Server.sendLogAsync()` is my own implementation of `Log.sendLogAsync()`. Moreover, I disabled the crash protection because I want to force the testers to kill the app when an unmanaged exception occurs.

My questions:

1. Is this code correct? I note that it works as I except on Android and on iOS, but Simulator becomes unresponsive when an exception inside an EasyThead is thrown. Moreover, the Simulator doesn't show the Dialog when an EasyThread exception is handled, while Android and iOS show it.
2. What is the usage of the `EasyThread t` and of the `<T> callback` as parameters of the method `onError(EasyThread t, T callback, Throwable error)` of `EasyThread.ErrorListener<T>`? What is `T` in this case?

Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread name is incorrect in the handling code, you would have printed out the EDT always:

```
    // Custom EasyThread error handling
    EasyThread.addGlobalErrorListener((t, c, e) -> {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        CN.callSerially(() -> {
            Log.p("\n\n--- Easy Thread CRASH REPORT ---\n", Log.ERROR);
            Log.p("Thead name: " + threadName);
            if(e != null) {
                  Log.e(e);
            }
            Server.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("EDT Exception", "Please be patient, report the following ERROR to the developers and then kill the app:\n\n" + e.getMessage(), null, null);
        });
    });
```

The simulator error is odd, I'd very much like to know what happens for that case. If this is reproducible in a debugger this should probably be easy to track.

- The `EasyThread` gives you a direct reference to the thread pool that triggered the error.
- The callback is essentially the `Runnable` or similar interface we were running e.g. `RunnableWithResult`. So `T` indicates the type of the interface. You can make it Object to keep things general.